# How to Separate out glyphs

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

This is the word of concern: કન્ક્લ્યુઝિવ
It is actually made up of these characters in gujarati script(Similar problem can arise with any Indic Script) ક ન ્ ક ્ લ ્ ય ુ ઝ િ વ.

I tried all special character searches etc but could not get a solution.

My objective is to convert કન્ક્લ્યુઝિવ to ક ન ્ ક ્ લ ્ ય ુ ઝ િ વ (adding space after each character which is combined as 1 glyph) in MS Word with either VBA macro or Find and replace or anyother way. You may also try in your pc with this example word. First remove space from "ક ન ્ ક ્ લ ્ ય ુ ઝ િ વ" and then try add space into it.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking till now in line of following in the Find box :
([।-૱])([।-૱])([।-૱])([।-૱])([।-૱])([।-૱])([।-૱])([।-૱])
Note: the range ।-૱ will include all gujarati script characters.
For this Word will return "too complex" due to more than 7 ranges specified with wild card on.
Hence, to circumvent the issue, we can use the following:
([।-૱])્([।-૱])્([।-૱])્([।-૱])([।-૱])
This will save number of ranges and we can search more complex glyphs.